# How to write a query to get the total amount shown below?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Below is my input table

```
Name  ID Amount
A     10 100
A     10 100
A     20 100
A     20 100
A     30 300
A     30 300
```

output required:

```
Name Id Amount
A    10 100
A    20 100
A    30 300
```

and second output should be like as below:

```
Name Amount
A    500
```

Comment: tag your correct rdbms

Comment: ... and _explain_ what the output represents. Your examples are not enough.

Comment: what I understand from your question u want distinct value from your table and total sum by name, check my answer below

Comment: Pro tip: on Stack Overflow we have a minimum effort requirement. This not only helps readers see which direction you're going in, and to tailor advice to your case, but it helps weed out folks who are looking for free labour. If you can show what code you tried in this question, by editing it, we would be most happy to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the followings:

for first output-

```
select distinct name, id, amount from tablename
```

for 2nd output -

```
select name, sum(amount)
from (select distinct name, id, amount from tablename)a
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following queries.

For first output:

```
select * from calc group by id;
```

For second output:

```
select name, sum(amount) from ( select * from calc group by id );
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
1 ) select distinct ID , Name, Amount from yourtable,

2 ) select Name, sum(Amount) Amount  from ( select distinct ID , Name, Amount from yourtable ) s group by Name